# The sudo group and /etc/sudoers

Tags: linux, files, sudo, group

In the sudoers file, there is a line of code that says `%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`.

```
[...]
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
[...]
```

If I changed it to something like: 
`bob ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`, will bob be the only user who will be able to enter any command using sudo? And will all the other users that are in the sudo group not be able to input any command?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: Thought it would be easier/better to ask, rather than do it and accidentally and somehow, like I always do, destroying something then having to fix it.

Comment: @Nick plus, I would do it on my Mac but it does not have the same sudo group and sudoers file. Mac and Linux in that respect, are not the same. The pic is from a private server that me and some people are trying to set up in a club, so I don’t want to accidentally screw anything up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the usual caveats*, yes, `bob` will be the only sudoer if you replace that line with one you proposed.

---

* Caveats: No other sudoers rules of import. For example, some Linux distros also have rules for root (allowing everything), or for the group `wheel` (of a similar nature to the `sudo` group), etc. `sudoers` can also include other files and directories, so those files and directories should also be checked.

Comment: If there were still other users who belonged to the sudo group, would they still be able to use sudo, but not be able to use every command like you would otherwise?

Comment: @HunterT. Use sudo for?

Comment: Use sudo for example: nanoing into a file that you have to use sudo for: `/etc/passwd`

Comment: @HunterT. what's the difference between that and "not be able to use every command like you would otherwise"?

Comment: I’ll rephrase, say there are two people who belong to the sudo group: bob and jeff. In the sudoers file, if I change `%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` to `bob ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`, would sudo essentially become useless to jeff?

Comment: @HunterT. do you want me to repeat the answer in the comments?

Comment: No you don’t. I am just trying to understand what point would there be to have a sudo group if your rights within the sudo group could be easily taken away and be modified by doing what I am talking about to the sudoers file. I am probably just overthinking things like I usually do.

Comment: @HunterT. root (and by extension, any sudoer) can change your password easily. What's the point of having a password, then? Root (and by extension, any sudoer) can wipe out your hard disk. What's the point of having an OS installed then?

Comment: I see where your coming from.

Comment: thank you for answering my question and explaining it to me!